# How to position a fixed background image on android webview?

Tags: cordova, webview, android-webview

I have a cordova app (using Ionic) where I am setting a fixed background image on a content div (which has a header above it). This works correctly expected in Chrome, and on iOS, but when I run the app on android (tested on 4.4.2), it seems to position the background image with respect to the div, instead of the viewport. Has anyone else dealt with this? Any Suggestions?

I set a background image like this:

```
.content-div {background: url(../my_image.svg) no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: 160px;
   background-position: 185px 478px;}
```

These screenshots show an example.
The black line is a div inside of the content div, positioned at "top: 478".

[image: Chrome]
[image: Android 4.4]

Comment: Your background looks Scaled so i think if you do 100% 100% on the size of the background image that will fill in the background instead of scaling it. w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: The size it set at 160px wide using the background-size property. The images may appear scaled because they are different size screens.

Comment: ahh its an SVG. is it full screen between the header and the footer or  in another div down below? if so try (background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;)

Comment: It was already no-repeat, I edited my code above to reflect that. Background-size 100% is not what I am looking for. I want it to be 160px wide, no matter what size screen you are on.

Comment: Ok its confusing because you are not showing your divs or the structure of your page in your question. Can you Inspect the element in a browser Like Xcode on a mac simulator and see the CSS. that way you can play around with it dynamically and view the Changes. Good Luck